# TTEST function using split arrays

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a simple TTEST in Excel with two groups but with the data in different columns.

Example: I want to run a two-tailed, homoscedastic Student’s t-Test between Group **A** (split between Column A and Column E) and Group **B** (split between Column B and Column F).
I tried

> =TTEST(A1:A4+E1:E4,B1:B4+F1:F4,2,2)

and, having named A1:A4+E1:E4 `range_1` and B1:B4+F1:F4 `range_2`:

> =TTEST(range_1,range_2,2,2)

The first gives an incorrect result (it treats the second parts of each Group as nulls), the second an error:

[image: SO17887184 question eample]
There is no mention [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/ttest-HP005209325.aspx) that the arrays must be of contiguous cells and I have not found mention of that as a requirement elsewhere.
Is there a formula to achieve the correct result where each array is of non-contiguous cells?

Comment: Hi pnuts, yes the results are different then if the groups were all in the same column, eg group A all in column A and group B all in column B.

Comment: thanks for trying pnuts - appreciate the effort.

Comment: If the arrays are small, try using `choose()` within `ttest()` [source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/514367-creating-array-non-adjacent-cells.html) if you don't want to use VBA. For VBA see [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/650380-making-single-array-from-non-contiguous-ranges.html)

Comment: Thanks RayStafarian, choose()  works ;-) clever but its so rigid as to render it in-practical for use, too bad though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do a T-Test on non-contiguous arrays using SUBTOTAL and OFFSET

[image: T-test non-contiguous example]